# How to CORS enable in jasper-server for reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, cors, jasperserver

I'm trying to consume API as a get request from jasper-server in my reactjs application. Unfortunately, I got error message "Cross-Origin Request Blocked".

I config web.xml file which is from jasperserver/webapp/web-inf and also config tomcat web.xml. Both are configured by using this filter.

```
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>http://10.11.200.42:3000</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
<param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
 </init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
<param-value>1800</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this location(**jaspersoft\jasperreports-server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF**) where you install your jasperosft and configure **web.xml** file using below code.

```
      <filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.csrf.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:port</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
        </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>1800</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: doesn't work on v7.8.0